# Transcription Output is very different for same audio for "Google Test our API" vs via our code

Tags: google-cloud-speech

We wish to transcribe an audio file via Google Speech to Text API. Providing same audio file with exact same configuration and transcription model, we are getting extremely different results as under:

1. When via "Google Speech UI" to test..Output is as expected and transcription is very good and accurate
2. When doing via our code and using same configuration, the output is very different --wrong spellings, no punctuations and wrong words as well

Attaching SS of both the scenarios along with output. Unable to identify any root cause as to why this is happening. Our same code used to give perfect output about 2 months back, suddenly the quality has dropped without any explanation.

Can you please help?

[Google Test API Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRdvL.png)
[Our Code Using Google API Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsSDS.png)

1. Tried checking billing plans..We were on paid plan and still on the same. No change there
2. Tried testing same audio on Google Speech UI -- very different result
3. Tried setting up new library in local server. Same issue. In local server, transcription is wrong whereas in actual Google Speech UI..it is perfect